# Many-to-many relationship constrains in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have entities `Word` and `Tag`. Both have `To-Many` relationship to each other, as well as inverse. The way I need to constrain it that:

- if I delete a Word then only the related Tags which has no Word pointing to them will be deleted
- if I delete a Tag which has Words pointing to it then just nullify those set items.

Is it possible to model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that needs to be handled in code.  You need to create custom subclasses for your Word and Tag entities and implement the `-prepareForDeletion` method in each.  Then you can check the logic and handle it appropriately.  I would also set the delete rule for the relationships between the entities as `deny`

Comment: Basically say in Word's `-prepareForDeletion` I have to check each tag and see if they are pointing to self, only then I delete the tag manually?

Comment: Other way around.  When a `Word` is being deleted you need to check if the associated `Tag` relationships **ONLY** point to that Word and delete them also.  Reverse that logic in the `Tag`.